# How do I create this type of paragraph

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website and i need a paragraph just like this.

[image: theirs]

Mine look like this:

[image: mine]

Here is the code :

```
 <section id="services"  style="background-image:url(img/header-bg2.png); background-size:cover; background-position:right; background-repeat:repeat; min-height:100vh">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#FFF">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="imagini/1.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="min-width:180px; min-height:180px" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"><br>
            Titlu de test Titlu de test Titlu de test <br><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:#FFF"><br>
            Aici vine contextul care este tot de test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="imagini/1.png" class="img-circle" width="200px" height="200px">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="imagini/1.png" class="img-circle" width="200px" height="200px">
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Not a PHP question. That is HTML/CSS.

Comment: why i cant saw images only with links ?

Comment: The [tour] and [help] pages can explain what you can (and can't) do based on the reputation you've earned. [ask] will help you write better questions that will get you answers more quickly.

Comment: Formatting of question. This is too broad add the HTML/CSS you currently have.

Comment: Ok! Sorry for bad format !! Now someone can help me pls ?

Comment: Add the code, no one wants to guess what elements and rules you currently have. There are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: @chris85 here is the code

Comment: You need to provide your CSS too.

Comment: Provide your `css` no one here would write code from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to make use of the css `position`.

You could try adding `position: relative` to your image parent and adding `position: absolute` to your image.

Then give your image a top value of -50%.  This will cause half of the image to move out of the parent by 50%.

See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cfqu2hms/1/

Comment: Thx for your time and help!!

Comment: sure.  no problem!